# Xfce: set time language to other than that of the system (interface)

Tags: xfce, locale, timezone, settings, language

I want o have English for my system interface and settings, but French for locale (region), ***including time*** (weekdays, months, which appear in conky etc).

But ***in Xfce the time language is set along with the system's, not with the locale/region***:

[image: language]

Can we set the time language separately from the main one (system, interface)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Edit he file `/etc/default/locale` and add/edit the line `LC_TIME=`

In Linux Mint Xfce:

```
sudo xed  /etc/default/locale
```

It looks like so:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Log out to see changes.

---

[Based on this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187450/925128)